# Regular expression for filenames that doesn't exclude whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex, file-extension

I have been using this regular expression to extract file names out of file path strings:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\w+[.]\w+$+");
```

This works, as long as there is no space in the file name.  For example:

```
r.Match("c:\somestuff\myfile.doc").Value = "myfile.doc"
r.Match("c:\somestuff\my file.doc").Value = "file.doc"
```

I need my regular expression to give me "my file.doc", and not just "file.doc"

I tried messing around with the expression myself.  In particular I tried adding \s+ after learning that that is for matching whitespaces.  I didn't get the results I hoped for.

I did devise a solution just to get the job done: I started at the end of the string, went backwards until a backslash was reached.  This gave me the file name in reverse order (i.e. cod.elifym) into an array of chars, then I used Array.Reverse() to turn it around.  However I'd like to learn how to achieve this by simply modifying my original regular expression.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? You know there's a class in .NET that'll return the file name for you? take a look at System.IO.Path.GetFileName.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  I was for some reason thinking that if I used System.IO.Path, I would need access to the actual files (which I don't).  But now I see you can just give it a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"[\w ]+\.\w+$");
```

Comment: I ultimately went with the System.IO.Path method, but since this directly answers the original question, I'll mark this one as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be a regular expression? Use [System.IO.Path.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

A [working regex](http://regexr.com?3216d) might simply look like:

```
[^\\]+$
```

Consider using:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)
```